# Google App Script - Increase Value based on a match in that row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of episode titles where team members can click a button and trigger a randomly selected title to us. This is being done with a formula in the sheet and not app script. I am currently using app script to add the date added and last modified timestamps when line items are created or updated, but I would like to track how often a title has been used.

Currently I've set up a script to execute when the +1 button is clicked that will automatically increase the value of the actively selected cell by 1, like a tally counter. However, this means that the user has to scroll down and find the matching title in the list, select the Tally cell for that row, and then click the +1 button.

I would like to use app script to do the following:

1. See the string in B3
2. Find the matching row based on B3
3. Find the Tally cell for that row (Col F)
4. Increase the tally cell in that row by 1

I've been searching everything I can find online with no luck. I'm just learning how to write scripts and am unsure how to find the right terms to search for answers to this. How can I structure this script?

Here are the scripts I've got set up on this sheet so far:

```
//Updates the sheet on button click to force re-roll the RAND function and select a new title in cell b3
function updateCheckbox() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  if (sheet.getRange('H3').isChecked() === true) {
    sheet.getRange('H3').setValue('FALSE');
  } else {
    sheet.getRange('H3').setValue('TRUE'); 
  }
}

//housing function to add/update timestamps
function onEdit(e) {
  addTimestamp(e);
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == "B3"){
    incrementDupe();
  }
}

//adds timestamps in Cols D and E, updates Col E when changes are made in that row
function addTimestamp(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Titles');
  var currentDate = new Date();

  if(col === 2 && row > 7 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Titles"){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,6).setValue(0);
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,5).setValue(currentDate);
    if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).getValue() == ""){
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue(currentDate);
      }
    }
  }

//Click tally cell for a row, click +1 button to increase the value in that cell
function plus1() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var numRange = sheet.getActiveRange;
var numAdd = numRange.getValue();
numRange.setValue(numAdd + 1);
}


//very rough start with automating the tally function
function incrementDupe(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Titles');
var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange("B3:E").getValues();
var chosenTitle = 
var 

//dataSheet.getRange()

//offset(0,2).getValue()

}
```

Example Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rpZMVl4jxQFptUacNq_LkHWtYAHnshWaRgoixMa6byc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

### Adding Tally whenever a Title is Selected

I understand that you are trying to add a point to tally whenever your title is selected. I have run through your code and implementation with Google Sheets. I can see that there is some error during the time that a title is being selected via a combination of your formula and Google Apps Script. What I did and what I suggest for you to do is give the randomization task with Google Apps Script using this sample script. This set of codes will require you to delete the formula on the "B3" cell.

### Google Apps Script Sample Code Randomize "B3":

```
function updateCheckbox() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Titles");
  var randomizerData = ss.getRange("B8:255").getValues().flat().filter(Boolean); //This will create a data representation of your references on the Google Sheets
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomizerData.length); // Creates the randomization.
  var randomValue = randomizerData[randomIndex];// This part is the one the gets the Random value so you can work with it.


  ss.getRange("B3:B4").setValue(randomValue);
//addToTally(); enable this if you want to have your Select A Title Button to worry about the Adding of Tally.
  
 }
```

In this example above,please take note that you have to change the getRange parameter that better suits your needs, I have created this assuming that your references below will not increase.Moreover here is the additional code for adding a Tally each time your title is selected.

### Google Apps Script Sample Code add 1 to Tally:

```
function addToTally(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Titles"); 

  var activeTitle = activeSheet.getRange("B3").getDisplayValue(); // This is where you are getting the value showed on the "B3" Cell
  console.log(activeTitle);
  var referenceRange = activeSheet.getRange("B8:F255");
  var referenceData = referenceRange.getValues(); // Gets the value on your Google Sheets
  for (var i = 0; i < referenceData.length; i++) {
    if (referenceData[i][0] === activeTitle) { // This will check which reference data have your currently selected title and add to value to the Tally row
      var tallyCell = activeSheet.getRange(i + 8, 6);
      var tally = tallyCell.getValue();
      console.log(tally);
      tallyCell.setValue(tally + 1);
    }
  }

}
```

### Here is the result of these Google Apps Script Codes:

[image: Test Result]

What I have showed you on the GIF was when I added the addToTally()
on the updateCheckbox() so it will be called by only 1 Button. You can freely add the addToTally() script to the +1 Button or call it on the updateCheckbox() so that it will be handled by Select a Title button.

### References:

[Filter](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)

[Flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

[Floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)